# How do I output the results of a batch file into a folder with the same name as the input file?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am currently using a batch file which uses a programm called CriPackTools to extract the contents of a CPK file.

```
@echo off 
for /r %%i in (*.cpk) do "CriPakTools.exe" "%%i" ALL
```

as you can see here it uses any cpk i drag onto the batch file and extracts the contents to the same directory.

Now how can I change it so it uses my XXXX.cpk, creates a folder named XXXX (the same as the file) and extracts its contents inside the folder.

Thanks

Comment: We have no idea if `CriPakTools` is designed to extract to anything other than the `.cpk` directory, without that information, we'd simply be guessing. Your question is off topic because here we help you to fix errors with your code, we do not write the code for you to your specification.

Comment: Your code does not use drag and drop input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the `CriPakTools.exe` extracting files into a current directory:

```
@echo off 
for /r %%i in (*.cpk) do (
    md "%%~dpni"
    pushd "%%~dpni"
    "CriPakTools.exe" "%%i" ALL
    popd
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `for /R` loop, you are looping through all subfolders. If a `.cpk` file is located in a folder different than the `%cd%` or the location of `CriPakTools.exe`, then the command will fail. I would suggest the following code:

```bat
@echo off

pushd "C:\path\with\cpks"
for /R "C:\path\with\cpks" %%A IN (*.cpk) do (
    cd "%%~dpA"
    mkdir "%%~nA"
    cd %%~nA
    "CriPakTools.exe" "%%~fA" ALL
)

cd "C:\path\with\cpks"
echo The operation has finished.
pause>nul
exit /b 0
```

This, may help you.